# Better way to check conservation in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

The partial differential equation in the `NDSolve` below is conservative (by construction) of $\int_{-1}^{+1} p(t,z)\ dz$ for all $t$.

```
tMax = 1;
sol = NDSolve[
  {
    Derivative[1, 0][p][t, z] == Derivative[0, 2][p][t, z],
    p[0, z] == (1 - z^2)^2 *Exp[-1 z^2],
    Derivative[0, 1][p][t, -1] == 0,
    Derivative[0, 1][p][t, +1] == 0
  },
  {p},
  {t, 0, tMax},
  {z, -1, 1},
  PrecisionGoal -> 1,
  AccuracyGoal -> 2
];
```

In order to check conservation, I find the percent difference between $\int_{-1}^{+1} p(t,z)\ dz$ and $\int_{-1}^{+1} p(0,z)\ dz$ for `timePoints = 20` values of `t` by repeated calls to `NIntegrate`.

```
timePoints = 20;
dt = tMax/timePoints;
int0 = p[0, z] /.
  sol //
    NIntegrate[#, {z, -1, 1}] & //
      Flatten;

intPercentDif = 
  Table[
    p[dt*i, z] /.
      sol //
        NIntegrate[#, {z, -1, 1}] & //
          Flatten //
            100*(# - int0)/int0 & //
              First //
                {dt*i, #} &,
    {i, 1, timePoints}
  ];

ListPlot[
  intPercentDif,
  AxesLabel -> {"time", "integral percent difference [%]"}
]
```

The plot shows that the error remains small for this case. This method is quite computationally demanding, and for my real problem, which is a more-complex set of coupled pdes, this check takes a very long time.

I'd like to check every time I simulate the system, but this check takes longer than the simulation itself. **Is there a better way to check for conservation?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of `NDSolve` is an interpolation function, so you can define its integral over `z` at a generic value of `t`. Then producing lists or plots is very fast.

```
sol2 = p /. First@NDSolve[{Derivative[1, 0][p][t, z] == Derivative[0, 2][p][t, z], 
                           p[0, z] == (1 - z^2)^2*Exp[-1 z^2], 
                           Derivative[0, 1][p][t, -1] == 0, 
                           Derivative[0, 1][p][t, +1] == 0}, {p}, {t, 0, tMax}, {z, -1, 1}, 
                           PrecisionGoal -> 1, AccuracyGoal -> 2] ;

cons[t_] = Integrate[sol2[t, z], {z, -1, 1}]

Plot[100 (cons[t]/int0[[1]] - 1), {t, 0, tMax}]
```

[image: plot]

If you need to manipulate the `InterpolatingFunction` further, you can use :

```
cons3[t_] = Integrate[
             FunctionInterpolation[3 sol2[t, z], {t, 0, tMax}, {z, -1, 1}][t, z], 
            {z, -1, 1}]

Plot[{cons[t], cons3[t]}, {t, 0, tMax}]
```

[image: plot3]

Comment: Thank you. I had tried to do something similar with `NIntegrate`, but was unsuccessful. Sometimes `InterpolatingFunction`s are a bit mysterious to me. This works great.

Comment: So, if I change variables after finding the solution `sol2` to give me `sol3`, I get a function of the `InterpolatingFunction`. Using `Integrate` on this takes a while to return the integral essentially unevaluated (it's a linear change of basis -- not complicated). Is there way to integrate this function of the `InterpolatingFunction` as before?

Comment: E.g. try `Integrate[3*sol2[t, z], {z, -1, 1}]` in the example above. Or `Integrate[(3 + z)*sol2[t, z], {z, -1, 1}]`.